# sears credit card starts with 50 -- fails regex

Tags: regex, credit-card

Most credit card regexes list mastercard as starting with a 5 and then having 1-5 as the second digit, though this one is from sears and has 5049 as the first four.  I don't really want to change the regex without knowing if any other non conventions are used.  Does anyone know if it's pretty safe to change it or if other alterations need be made also?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your RegEx is faulty :-)  **[Edit: If you want to support Sears cards, which is the premise of your question]**

There is an accurate list of issuer numbers on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Issuer_Identification_Numbers

It includes 5049 for Sears.

I suggest creating one or more unit tests for each listed issuer number and validating your RegEx with those unit tests.

**UPDATE**

There are plenty of widely accepted credit cards that start with "50", so your RegEx is still faulty if it asserts the 2nd digit is in the range 1-5.

Examples (From the Wiki link):

```
500235 National Bank of Canada
500766 Bank of Montreal
```

If you are selling things that are allowed to be sold to public benfit recipients (e.g. welfare recipients) also the EBT cards e.g.:

```
507683 Missouri EBT Card
```